# The performance about if statements in python

Tags: python

I prefer to assign conditions to variables when I have to write a long if statement.

But when the conditions are time-wasting, I think it is not good because the interpreter should run all the conditions even if just few conditions should be run.

In the codes below for example, the `test1` is more readable but slower than `test2` because `con1` is `True` and `test2` just run only one condition.

(I know the logic is ugly, because it is just for example)

```py
def x(arg):
    '''
    A time-wasting method
    '''
    res = 0
    for i in range(2000000):
        res += i * arg
    return res

def test1():
    con1 = x(1) > 1000.24
    con2 = x(2) < 2000
    con3 = x(3) < 3000
    con4 = x(4) < 4000
    con5 = x(5) < 555
    con6 = x(6) < 666
    con7 = x(7) < 777
    con8 = x(8) < 888
    con9 = x(9) < 234
    con10 = x(10) < 345
    con11 = x(11) < 456
    con12 = x(12) < 445
    con13 = x(13) < 745
    con14 = x(14) < 3475
    con15 = x(15) < 334545
    con16 = x(16) < 323445
    con17 = x(17) < 37645
    con18 = x(18) < 3445
    con19 = x(19) < 37745
    con20 = x(20) < 3455

    if con1 or con2 or con3 or con4 or con5 or con6 or con7 or con8 or con9 or \
       con10 or con11 or con12 or con13 or con14 or con15 or con16 or con17 or \
       con18 or con19 or con20:
        print('test1')

def test2():
    if x(1) > 1000.24 or x(2) < 2000 or x(3) < 3000 or x(4) < 4000 or x(5) < 555 or \
       x(6) < 666 or x(7) < 777 or x(8) < 888 or x(9) < 234 or x(10) < 345 or \
       x(11) < 456 or x(12) < 445 or x(13) < 745 or x(14) < 3475 or x(15) < 334545 or \
       x(16) < 323445 or x(17) < 37645 or x(18) < 3445 or x(19) < 37745 or x(20) < 3455:
        print('test2')
```

What is the best way to deal with that?

Comment: do you have `<`/`>` checks in your code or is it just for example?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov It is just for example!

Comment: I don‘t think test2 would be less readable if formatted like your assignment in test1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have a long list of `or` statements, you probably want to formulate those conditions as a list of uniform predicates and use `any`. E.g.:

```
predicates = [
    (2, 2000),
    (3, 3000),
    ...
]

if x(1) > 1000.24 or any(x(y) < z for y, z in predicates):
    ...
```

In this case all but the first case differ only in the specific numbers used, so writing them this way is the most compact. You can of course also use a list of callables, which can do anything you need:

```
from functools import partial

predicates = [
    lambda: x(1) > 1000.24,
    lambda: x(2) < 2000,
    ...
    partial(sum, range(42)),
    ...
]

if any(p() for p in predicates):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `any` when you need to lazily `or` multiple expressions. You can feed it with a generator that goes through the parameters of comparison:

```
test_parameters = ((2, 2000), (3, 3000), (4, 4000), (5, 555))

if x(1) < 1000.24 or any(x(a) > b for a, b in test_parameters):
   ...
```

You can also use `all` to `and` expressions.

Answer (score 1):

We can use containers and [`any` function](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) here like

```
from operator import gt, lt

def test3():
    domain = range(1, 21)
    predicates_with_bounds = [(gt, 1000.24),
                              (lt, 2000),
                              (lt, 3000),
                              (lt, 4000),
                              (lt, 555),
                              (lt, 666),
                              (lt, 777),
                              (lt, 888),
                              (lt, 234),
                              (lt, 345),
                              (lt, 456),
                              (lt, 445),
                              (lt, 745),
                              (lt, 3475),
                              (lt, 334545),
                              (lt, 323445),
                              (lt, 37645),
                              (lt, 3445),
                              (lt, 37745),
                              (lt, 3455)]
    if any(predicate(x(element), bound)
           for element, (predicate, bound) in zip(domain,
                                                  predicates_with_bounds)):
        print('test3')
```

or by "switching" `<` -> `>` and using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial) we can make container of predicates with bounds bounded (sorry for pun)

```
from functools import partial
from operator import gt, lt

def test4():
    domain = range(1, 21)
    predicates = [partial(lt, 1000.24),
                  partial(gt, 2000),
                  partial(gt, 3000),
                  partial(gt, 4000),
                  partial(gt, 555),
                  partial(gt, 666),
                  partial(gt, 777),
                  partial(gt, 888),
                  partial(gt, 234),
                  partial(gt, 345),
                  partial(gt, 456),
                  partial(gt, 445),
                  partial(gt, 745),
                  partial(gt, 3475),
                  partial(gt, 334545),
                  partial(gt, 323445),
                  partial(gt, 37645),
                  partial(gt, 3445),
                  partial(gt, 37745),
                  partial(gt, 3455)]
    if any(predicate(x(element))
           for element, predicate in zip(domain, predicates)):
        print('test4')
```

Comment: you could also consider using `enumerate` instead of `range`/`zip`. Obviously you'd need to begin the enumeration at 1 instead of the default zero.

Answer (score 0):

Assign lambda expressions to the variables, so they aren't executed until you call them in the `if` statement.

```
def test1():
    con1 = lambda: x(1) > 1000.24
    con2 = lambda: x(2) < 2000
    con3 = lambda: x(3) < 3000
    ...

    if con1() or con2() or con3() or ...:
        print('test1')
```

But really I think you need to re-examine the logic of your program. Why does it need so many conditions in a single `if` statement? Is there some pattern to it that you can extract to simplify it?

Another method would be to make a list that represents all the comparisons:

```
cons = [('>', 1000.24), ('<', 2000), ('<', 3000), ...]
def test1():
    for i, test in enumerate(cons):
        if test[0] == '<':
            if x(i+1) < test[1]:
                print('test')
                break
        elif x(i+1) > test[1]:
            print('test')
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it data driven with something like:

```
# Each item has index, less-than-value and greater-than-value.
data = [[1, None, 1000.24], [2, 2000, None], … [19, 37745, None], [20, 3455, None]]

outcome = False
for item in data:
    if item[1] is not None: outcome = outcome or x[item[0]] < item[1]
    if item[2] is not None: outcome = outcome or x[item[0]] > item[2]

# Outcome now contains result of all data driven comparisons, or'ed together.
```